# Where is the clickhouse config.xml in Mac OS

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to clickhouse. I tried the clickhouse on both Ubuntu and MacOS. As for the ubuntu version, I know the server config.xml is under the /etc/clickhouse-server/ folder. However, on the Mac OS I cannot find the config.xml with the path with the quick start installation method provided [here](https://clickhouse.com/#quick-start).

```
wget 'https://builds.clickhouse.com/master/macos/clickhouse'
chmod a+x ./clickhouse
./clickhouse
```

I know I can build a clickhouse to get the config file in the /etc/ folder. But I'm wondering where is the config.xml file if I choose to pre download the applicaion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download this https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/programs/server/config.xml

and then run `./clickhouse -c config.xml`

---

Or you can use brew (Intel and M1 both are supported) https://github.com/Altinity/homebrew-clickhouse
then files will be in `/usr/local/`

```
/usr/local/etc/clickhouse-server/
/usr/local/var/lib/clickhouse/
/usr/local/var/log/clickhouse-server/

/usr/local/bin/clickhouse-server
/usr/local/bin/clickhouse-client
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the way to go. I noticed that there is a ./clickhouse install method but it will not run in Mac OS. Guess I will need to attach a xml file  each time I launch it.